# How can one politely ask unknown users to consider stopping serial votings?

Tags: discussion, users, serial-voting

For one week, every day I received a large amount of upvotes which have been identified as serial upvotes and thus undone. Of course, I do not know who casted the votes. Given the definition of "serial voting", the votes have been cast by one or at most a few users. I perfectly understand that the upvoter does not mean to do harm, but rather the opposite. However, because of the serial voting policy (which I am fine with) they may achieve the opposite of what they want, meaning that if among the upvoted posts there were one or two which they really read and found useful, the corresponding votes will be annihilated as well.

My question:

> Is there a way to politely ask the unknown user(s) to consider stopping that practice?

(Of course, there is a chance that the serial upvoters read this post, and the problem will be solved by this. My question is also on the case that they don't. Could then the moderators contact the user(s) and ask them to consider stopping?)

Comment: Mods can see 'serial upvoter' information, at least to some extent. I'll take a look at your stats.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks! Seems to have worked. I am wondering if you want to write an official answer, perhaps containing an official way of contacting the moderators (e.g. by flagging one of the posts that got serially upvoted or whatever is more appropriate).

Comment: @marmot: You can always troll the [list of users sorted by number of votes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters). Here is, for example, an [anonymous user](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/69318/user69318) with fairly aggressive [voting activity](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/69318/user69318?tab=topactivity)...

Comment: @Werner Yes, that's a way to gather a lot of information, especially if you compare their reputation change to the reputation change shown under activity. This allows one to find out who downvoted how many answers. However, I am not sure if this allows one to identify serial voters. After all, their votes get undone. Are you saying that the [list of users sorted by number of votes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters) also counts votes that have been undone?

Comment: @marmot: I don't know exactly what serial voting reversal undoes. Surely the reputation associated with it, but not sure whether it returns votes to the voter (I doubt it, since it's usually done after the fact and they get a fresh batch of votes every day) or changes the score of the voted posts.

Comment: @Werner I also do not know but I would assume that, yes, they cannot vote any more at that day because they already hit the limit but after the reversal has taken place their votes won't appear in the [list of users sorted by number of votes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters). Whether or not this is the case both of us seem not to know, but you may agree that contacting some users who cast some large numbers of votes and asking them to stop serial voting might not be a good plan because we may suspect the wrong users.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Sure: it looks like there was an 'over-enthusiastic' user, I'll talk to them

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks!

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry to bug you again but it (re)started. (Could there be an automatized message to the serial voter saying: "Your votes have been reversed. Please consider voting only selected posts."?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat That's one for the Powers: we don't control this locally. (They are mainly concerned with serial downvotes, so I'm not sure how much they've really looked a this.) One for the network-wide meta site I think.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks! There is indeed a [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49666/603947). Not sure if I agree with the accepted answer, they seem to be mostly concerned in avoiding to define how many votes are considered serial.

Comment: @JosephWright If you have a chance, maybe you could send one more message? The serial voting is on and off, currently it is more on than off...

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat They've now been picked up by the site tools: I've sent them a mod message

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks once more!